# MongoDB aggregation pipeline to modify objects in array in an smart way

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection which documents have an array of objects. Like this:

```
{
  _id: ...,
  a: [
    {
      aa: "foo1"
      bb: "bar1"
    },
    {
      aa: "foo2"
      bb: "bar2"
    },
    {
      aa: "foo3"
      bb: "bar3"
    }
    ...
  ],
  b: ...
}
```

I want to modify some of the fields of the object and left the rest untouched. I'm using the aggregation framework for that, with three stages: unwind of the array, modification of the objects (now at root level in the document) and finally re-grouping by `_id` to get the array back.

```
{
  $unwind: "a"
},
{
  $set: {"a.aa": {$concat: ["prefix-", "$a.aa", "-suffix"]}}
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    a: {$push: "$a"},
    b: {$first: "$b"}
  }
}
```

So far so good.

The problem is that I don't have only one field in addition to the array. I have lot of them (~10) so the group stage is actually like this:

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    a: {$push: "$a"},
    b: {$first: "$b"},
    c: {$first: "$c"},
    d: {$first: "$d"},
    // a lot of fields here
  }
}
```

which is error prone to write.

Is there some smarter way of doing this without explicitly include all the attributes in the group stage?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using `$unwind` followed by `{$group: { _id: "$_id", ...` is typically a poor approach. Have a look at `$filter` and `$map` or `$reduce` if the operations are more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample data, it could be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         a: {
            $map: {
               input: "$a",
               in: {
                  $mergeObjects: [
                     "$$this",
                     { aa: { $concat: ["prefix-", "$$this.aa", "-suffix"] } }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```